# How to ask input from a QML Dialog multiple times?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am not very experienced with Qt and I have trouble doing what I want.

In my application, I search for archive files with password on a disk (that part works) and I want to ask the user for the password each time I find one new encrypted archive.

If I find multiple files while user hasn't given any password, I want the dialog for the first password to stay visible until that password is given and then the dialog for the next password can show and so on.

I use some sort of queue to remember which archives need a password, and I am trying to show and hide an unique dialog (actually a Popup) with the info of each archive and get the password from a TextField inside. In the meantime my application is doing other stuff in the c++ code like searching for archives and extracting them when a given password is OK.

My problem is that it is not really working. The dialog shows the first time, I get the first password but then the dialog doesn't show for the next password. Sometimes I can see the dialog a second time, for a few milliseconds, before it disappears without user interaction. My application is blocked because it cannot go on without the unasked passwords.

I get that I am doing something wrong but I don't get what exactly.
Can anyone help ?

I don't know if I was very clear, English is (obviously) not my mother tongue.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.

I did a component based on a Popup.
Inside the onClicked function of the Check or Skip buttons I was doing two things: send accepted() or refused() to trigger custom actions and then close the dialog.

I was doing that in that order, so the accepted or refused action, which among others things triggered the visibility for the "next" password dialog, occurred before the close event, which was setting the dialog visibility to false.

I switched the order and it's way better.
I feel a little silly now but at least I found it.